# C++ unlimited parameters to array

Tags: c++

I have a function with following signature

```
char requestApiCall(int num, const wchar_t* pParams = 0, ...)
{
...
}
```

Now I want to to get all pParams in an array (or to be able to iterate over it). I know this is possible with some macros, but I have no idea how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I'm using MinGW if it matters.

**UPDATE**

---

my question caused confusion. I will try to clarify (sorry for my grammar). Both Object Pascal and C# has the ability to pass unlimited amount of parameters to a method. In C# we achieve this with params keyword:

```
void Foo(params string[] strs)
{
...
}
Foo("first", "second", "another one", "etc");
```

I want to achieve same result in C++ without using any object/class. In my case, type safety is not a concern, but if there is a type safe way to achieve that goal, I will gladly hear your comments :)

Thanks

Comment: What does "Get all pParams in an array" mean?

Comment: Do you to write the function but keep the signature the same? Or can you change the signature?

Comment: @Seth Carnegie it means that I want to access all the pParams passed to the function. As you know that function accepts unlimited number of wchar_t*. I want to access all the wchar_t* passed to that function

Comment: "All the pParams" doesn't mean what you think it means. `pParam` is just the name of an argument to your function. And no, that function doesn't just accept an unlimited number of `wchar_t*`, it accepts a large number of _any_ type of parameters.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie thanks, I didn't know that. I'm a newbie in C++ :)

Comment: How are you exactly using signature `requestApiCall(int num, const wchar_t* pParams = 0, ...)` ? If you can edit your question for that then I think it can be done using macros easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look at the functions and macros declared in `stdarg.h`.  Here is a tutorial that explains it.

http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html

I'm not sure what your function parameters are supposed to represent but I think you'll find that it needs to change.

By the way, I find that for C++ I can usually avoid variadic functions.  This has the advantage of preserving type safety.  Are you sure you really need a variadic function?

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm quite sure I need it :-). The link you pointed only explains how to use that macros with integers. I need the same which works with pointers of string. :(

Comment: The macros work the same way with pointers, just replace int with const wchar_t*. For instance a[i] = va_arg(ap, const wchar_t*);

Comment: @Davita - If you just need to pass a variable number of strings to your function you might consider passing them in a std::vector<std::string> (or std::vector<std::wstring>.  Doing this preserves type safety.  The problem with stdargs is that the type of each parameter in the variable argument list can be anything.

Comment: Thanks Sean, the problem is that I can't use any classes/objects in my code, only pure C functions, also I can't compile to C due to QtCreator's limitation. Type safety is not a problem for me, because the method will be passed only wchar_t and nothing else. Thanks again for your help, I'll check your answer tomorrow and accept it if everything goes well :) +1 in the meantime

Answer (score 2):

Using variadic function arguments is a dangerous and tricky business, and almost surely there is a better way - for example, you might pass an `std::vector<std::wstring>&` to your function!

OK, that said, here's how to use variadic arguments. The key point is that **it is your responsibility to know the number and types of the arguments**!

```
#include <cstdarg>

char requestApiCall(int num, const wchar_t* pParams, ...)
{
   va_list ap;             // the argument pointer
   va_start(ap, pParams);  // initialize it with the right-most named parameter

   /** Perform magic -- YOU have to know how many arguments you are getting! **/

   int a = va_arg(ap, int);      // extract one int
   double d = va_arg(ap, double) // one double
   char * s = va_arg(ap, char*)  // one char*
   /* ... and so forth ... */

   va_end(ap);             // all done, clean up
}
```

Just for completeness, I would redefine the function as this:

```
char requestApiCall(std::vector<std::wstring> & params)
{
  for (std::vector<std::wstring>::const_iterator it = params.begin(), end = params.end(); it != end; ++it)
  {
    // do something with *it
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kerrek, but As I mentioned in above comment, I cannot use any classes or objects, because technical reasons. Also is it a mandatory for requestApiCall to know the amount of parameters passed to it? I mean, if it will receive only wchar_t* pointer, I can call va_arg until it returns 0. won't this work? anyway I'll try in several hours. Thanks

Comment: No, there is **no** generic way of knowing the number of arguments! You *have* to pass that information inside the non-variadic arguments somehow -- for example in the first `num` variable. Maybe give some more backround info on how you're using this function in context?

Answer (score 0):

A good example of what you are trying to accomplish is the exec family of functions. exec() takes an variable list of arguments all of which are expected to be const char*. The last item is a NULL ((char*)0). The last item is the indicator for when the list of items is complete.

You can use the variadic macros in stdargs.h as others have described.